Slow booting after update on Mantic Minotaur
This is the screenshot (Lenovo Thinkpad x250) I've been stuck at this 4 hours long, whats wrong, what should i do?


Can you access a shell if you press CTRL+ALT+F4? If so, then try logging in and then run sudo apt update and sudo apt dist-upgrade and possibly also sudo apt -f install. Also, do you have anything special like an additional GPU that possibly needs a driver, Nvidia, AMD, etc.?
